# How to fix image position in latex if [H], [h], [h!] don't work, and usepackage{float} is already added

Tags: graphics, floats

I have a Latex section that has text and a bunch of added images. Some text followed by an image is leaving a huge blank space between the text and the image. This happens everytime an image appears for this section.

`\usepackage{float}` is already added. And I have already tried changing `[H]` for `[h]` or `[h!]` in the following code:

```
\begin{figure}[h!]
\begin{center}
  \includegraphics[scale=0.5]{van_gogh.jpg}
  \label{fig:VanGogh}
    \caption{Imagen}
 \end{center}
\end{figure}
```

What can I now do to try to fix this?

This is how it looks: [image: blank space]

THANKS

Comment: What should the fix be? Should the text flow better around the figure? Then allow it to float by using `[htbp]` as the float specification (for example), not `[H]` or *only* `[h]` (which the compiler will complain about anyway). Possible duplicate: [How to influence the position of float environments like figure and table in LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/39017/5764)

Comment: Using [H] and [h!] is not a *remedy* against large spaces, it is normally the source of the problem.

Comment: Not knowing your document, we cant help you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to influence the position of float environments like figure and table in LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39017/how-to-influence-the-position-of-float-environments-like-figure-and-table-in-lat)

Comment: Please make an example that shows the problem you can delete all code not related to the float (which is most of the code that you have posted) and you can use `example-image` as the test image as it is generally available. But make a complete document that shows your problem.  But it is not clear that you have a problem. The only purpose of `\begin{figure}` is to allow the figure to move, so it sounds like it is working as expected.

Comment: Another possibility is that there is a lot of white space in the image itself.  Using `\fbox{\includegraphics{...}}` will show you whether you need to clip the image.

Answer (score 4):

You don't *have* to float an image if you don't want to. Float means "let LaTeX decide where it goes", i.e. the position "floats" and isn't fixed. If you're wanting "H!" or similar, really, you don't want a float (and indeed, afaik, "h!" basically doesn't do anything). Use the `caption` package, and its captionof command to turn any environment (like the center environment) into a figure.

The figure will now appear exactly where it appears in the text, and the text will flow around it normally. Sounds like LaTeX is putting your figure on a float page right now.

```
\begin{center}
  \includegraphics[scale=0.5]{van_gogh.jpg}
  \captionof{figure}{Imagen}
  \label{fig:VanGogh}
\end{center}
```

Comment: it didn't work :(

Comment: @OfeliayOrquesta in your question and here you just say "It didn't work" but these commands work as designed. They may not do what you expected, but we do not know what you expect. You need to provide example code that we can run, and say _exactly_ what error you got.

Answer (score 1):

Withou a full MWE it is hard to reproduce your problem. So I can not exactly reproduce what you mean with "huge blank space between the text and the image". `[h]`,`[H]` etc. influence the position of a float not the space beneath it. If you want to reduce the space between a figure and the text below like I in Figure A, you can achieve this with `\vspace{value}`. I made a new command to reduce the space `\newcommand{\redspace}{\vspace{-4.5mm}}`. As you can see in figure B.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\newcommand{\redspace}{\vspace{-4.5mm}} % adjust space value to your needs


\begin{document}
    
    \lipsum[1]
    \begin{figure}[h!]
        \begin{center}
            \includegraphics[scale=0.5]{example-image-a}
            \label{fig:VanGogh}
            \caption{Imagen}
        \end{center}
    \end{figure}

    \lipsum[1]
    
        \lipsum[1]
    \begin{figure}[h!]
        \begin{center}
            \includegraphics[scale=0.5]{example-image-a}
            \label{fig:VanGogh}
            \caption{Imagen}
        \end{center}
    \redspace
    \end{figure}
    \lipsum[1]
    
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It got fixed only when using `\lipsum[1]` , but if I remove it and substitute it with `\redspace`  it still leaves a blank space of the size of a paragraph. The space appears before the image: text - space - image, and not after the image. It would be difficult to give a short code for this text which is 80 pages long, but I edited my question.

Comment: Could you provide a MWE. I cannot reproduce your space problem. When I type for exampe **Text** -- `\vspace{-3mm}` or `\redspace`  -- **Image** -- `\vspace{-3mm}` or `\redspace` -- **Text**. the space is reduced. independent from `\lispum[1]`, it just adds text.

Comment: yes, `\lipsum[1]` adds a Lorem Ipsum text, I noticed. Space was removed when adding text in this way, but not without it. If I don't get fix this, I will try to provide a small example reproducing the problem.

Comment: I re edited the question, and copied the packages that I am currently using. As the document is using several images, IDK how would I provide a brief example. Thanx for the suggestion you already did. It helped, becaused it occured to me that that could be a solution, but it wasn't.

Comment: sorry but it absolutely wrong to use a vspace in the main document flow and a figure that is taken out of the document flow to be re-inserted elsewhere. The cspace will be left spacing the paragraphs at that point unless you get accidentally lucky and the figure is inserted next to the space node created by the vspace.